# VBA Excel Compare sheets with nested For

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, do-while

I want to compare every row of NBG_Data sheet with every row of Comparison_Data sheet , so i want each row of NBG_Data to be compared with all the rows of the Comparison_Data Sheet then go to the next row , till it reaches the MAX_Row ,the issue is that i couldn't Nest the For loop (which i really wanted) so i am trying the Do loop , but when i start the error is "Loop without Do"
If anyone please tell me what I did wrong in the Do loop or better modify the for so i can have a nested working for loop .

```
For Row = 2 To MAX_Row


CompMonth = Worksheets(NBG_ComparisonDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, SOP).Value
CompMonth = DatePart("m", CompMonth)

CompYear = Worksheets(NBG_ComparisonDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, SOP).Value
CompYear = DatePart("yyyy", CompYear)


CompCarmaker = Worksheets(NBG_ComparisonDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, Carmaker).Value
CompProject = Worksheets(NBG_ComparisonDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, Project).Value
CompFamily = Worksheets(NBG_ComparisonDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, Family).Value
CompStatus = Worksheets(NBG_ComparisonDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, Status).Value
CompShare = Worksheets(NBG_ComparisonDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, Share).Value


Do While Row <= 2

NBGMonth = Worksheets(NBG_DataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, SOP).Value
NBGMonth = DatePart("m", NBGMonth)

NBGYear = Worksheets(NBG_DataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, SOP).Value
NBGYear = DatePart("yyyy", NBGYear)

NBGCarmaker = Worksheets(NBG_DataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, Carmaker).Value
NBGProject = Worksheets(NBG_DataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, Project).Value
NBGFamily = Worksheets(NBG_DataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, Family).Value
NBGStatus = Worksheets(NBG_DataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, Status).Value
NBGShare = Worksheets(NBG_DataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, Share).Value

Row = Row + 1


 ' StatusBar Show

 Application.StatusBar = "VerifySumofShares. Progress: " & Row & " of " & MAX_Row


        If (NBGMonth = CompMonth And NBGYear = CompYear And CompCarmaker = NBGCarmaker And CompProject = NBGProject And CompFamily = NBGFamily And NBGStatus <> "LOST" And CompStatus <> "LOST" And CompShare + NBGShare <= 99 And CompShare + NBGShare > 100) Then



            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "A").Value = Row
            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "B").Value = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, Project).Value
            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "C").Value = GetMonthAndQuarter(Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, SOP).Value)
            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "D").Value = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, Family).Value
            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "E").Value = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, Responsible).Value

           ' Region As String
            Region = ""

            'Add any other GeoRegion which is also responsible in the recorded data


            If Worksheets(NBG_DataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, "BC") Then
            Region = Region + "@EMEA"
            End If

            If Worksheets(NBG_DataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, "BD") Then
            Region = Region + "@AMERICAS"
            End If

            If Worksheets(NBG_DataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, "BE") Then
            Region = Region + "@GCSA"
            End If

            If Worksheets(NBG_DataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, "BF") Then
            Region = Region + "@JAPAN&KOREA"
            End If


            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "F").Value = Region

            'Count the number of the cases recorded


            Issue_SumofSharesCnt = Issue_SumofSharesCnt + 1

            'If there is no items , the Message to show


        ElseIf (Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, SOP).Value = "There are no items to show in this view.") Then


    End If

     Loop Until Row = MAX_Row

Next Row
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a hybrid between a `Do While...Loop` and a `Do...Loop Until` loop, which VBA doesn't know how to interpret.

Either change:

```
    Do While Row <= 2
```

to:

```
    Do
```

to make a valid `Do...Loop Until` loop.

Or change:

```
    Loop Until Row = MAX_Row
```

to:

```
    Loop
```

to make a valid `Do While...Loop` loop.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: the code worked perfectly but athere is a problem , now the "Next Row" (For loop) does not work , if you please can help me .

Comment: You can't update the current outer `For- Next` loop iterator (`Row`) inside the loop itself (you have that `Row = Row + 1` inside the inner `Do While Row <= 2` loop). You might want to turn the outer `For Row = 2 To MAX_Row - Next Row` loop into a `Do - While Row <= MAX_Row` one

Comment: Okay , Thank you :)